# matrix class C++ as matlab operator overload

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, numerical-methods

I have a class that defines a matrix of dimensions mxn like this:

```
class Matrix{
  protected:
  int m;
  int n;
  double* mat:
  public:
  // accessors, constructors, destructors, etc.
  void assignvalue(int, int, double);
}
```

Right now if I need to assign a value on position i,j I have a function assignvalue that takes the positions i, j and does the magic and assigns a double value to that position.  However, it would be really nice if I could assign a value like you do in matlab or in R.

```
mymatrix(i,j) = 1.0;
```

Can you give me a hint on what operator(s) I need to overload?  Thanks.

Comment: Morwenn's answer is correct, but my rule of thumb is to try not to re-invent the wheel.  Find a library that already provides linear algebra operations.  Lately, I've been using Eigen3, and I have been very satisfied with it.

Comment: It is a thesis project and part of the problem is to reinvent the wheel.   But thanks for the advice.  It makes sense.

Comment: Of course!  Everyone should reinvent the wheel once, just to learn how it works.  But not for production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `m` represents the height of your Matrix and `n` represents the width, overloading `operator()` this way should do the trick:

```
double& Matrix::operator()(size_t i, size_t j)
{
    return mat[i*m+j];
}

const double& Matrix::operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const
{
    return mat[i*m+j];
}
```

This way, you can write something like this:

```
void f(Matrix & mymatrix ) {
   mymatrix(2, 3) = 5.0; // Calls the first function
   // ...
}
void f(Matrix const & m) {
   double a = m(1, 5); // Calls the second one
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  That helps me to get the value from the matrix.  Like a = mymatrix(i, j);  but I'm looking for the opposite.  More like mymatrix(i,j) = a;

Comment: It also works since there are two versions of the function: the `const` and the non-`const` one. The `const` will be used to retrieve the value while the other will be used to set it.

Comment: Note that the comment `// Calls the second one` is not correct. Dispatch is done using the type of the object on which the member function is called, which in this case is the same in both use lines. Assuming that the first one compiles, `mymatrix` is a non-const object of type `Matrix` and thus the second line will call exactly the same operator